# How to retrieve key value from custom.config file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config

I am able to get Key values from app.config file by below way, Looking for to retrieve it from other.config file. I need to declare all key values in separate .config file.

How can we allocate ConfigurationManager class for other.config file ?

**App.Config :**

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Title" value="Configuration Example"/>
    <add key="Language" value="CSharp"/>
 </appSettings>
```

**Key Retrieval by ConfigurationManager class:**

```
var title = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Title"];
var lang = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Language"];
```

Unfortunately, I found all examples for default app.config or web.config file.

Is it possible to manage it with custom.config file ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use configSource

web.config / app.config, Replace appSettings section with `<appSettings configSource="ShareAppSettings.debug.config"/>`

Then have a external file called "ShareAppSettings.debug.config" with all the settings in

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Verify that the External file has the property set to Copy to Output Directory.
Load the setting via

```
var version = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"];
```

Comment: Without declaring anything in class, I retrieved key values directly from app.config.  Because ConfigurationManager class is inbuilt for it. According to your solution, What is declaration for custom.config file by which ConfigurationManager class should point t?

Comment: There is nothing, It will work in the same way, the code will see the external file the same as the normal one

Answer (score 0):

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var val=config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
```

Comment: Not working. It throws error as " System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection.this[string].**get** returned null "

Comment: If you have any blog reference please share

Comment: sorry, don't have any blog reference. Are you sure the configPath is right? config.HasFile helps check if you get the configuration file.